# The code from react-router-dom of the old version does not work on react-router-dom of the new version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a consts.js file

```js
export const ADMIN_ROUTE = '/admin'
export const LOGIN_ROUTE = '/login'
export const REGISTRATION_ROUTE = '/registration'
export const SHOP_ROUTE = '/'
export const BASKET_ROUTE = '/basket'
export const DEVICE_ROUTE = '/product'
```

I have a routes.js file

```
import Admin from "./pages/Admin"
import Auth from "./pages/Auth"
import Basket from "./pages/Basket"
import DevicePage from "./pages/DevicePage"
import Shop from "./pages/Shop"
import {
  ADMIN_ROUTE,
  BASKET_ROUTE,
  DEVICE_ROUTE,
  LOGIN_ROUTE,
  REGISTRATION_ROUTE,
  SHOP_ROUTE
} from "./utils/consts"

export const authRoutes = [
  {
    path: ADMIN_ROUTE,
    Component: Admin
  },
  {
    path: BASKET_ROUTE,
    Component: Basket
  }
]

export const publicRoutes = [
  {
    path: SHOP_ROUTE,
    Component: Shop
  },
  {
    path: LOGIN_ROUTE,
    Component: Auth
  },
  {
    path: REGISTRATION_ROUTE,
    Component: Auth
  },
  {
    path: DEVICE_ROUTE + '/:id',
    Component: DevicePage
  },
]
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import AppRouter from "./components/AppRouter";

function App() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRouter/>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

AppRouter.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authRoutes, publicRoutes } from '../routes';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const isAuth = false;
  return (
    <Switch>
      {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) => 
        <Route key={path} path={path} component={Component} exact />
      )}
      {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) => 
        <Route key={path} path={path} component={Component} exact />
      )}
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default AppRouter;
```

I get the error, `export 'Switch' (imported as 'Switch') was not found in 'react-router-dom'`. I tried all variants, tried to replace `Switch` with `Router` and so on, but nothing helps. I know they removed `Switch` in `react-router-dom@6.0`, but I don't understand how to fix this code to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The `Switch` component was replaced by the [`Routes`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/routes) component in `react-router-dom@6`. Additionally the `Route` component API changed as well, instead of the `component` and `render` and `children` function props there is now a single `element` prop taking a `React.ReactNode`, a.k.a JSX, value.

Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authRoutes, publicRoutes } from '../routes';

const AppRouter = () => {
  const isAuth = false;
  return (
    <Routes> // <-- Directly wrap all Route components
      {isAuth && authRoutes.map(({path, Component}) => (
        <Route
          key={path}
          path={path}
          element={<Component />} // <-- ReactNode/JSX
        />
      ))}
      {publicRoutes.map(({path, Component}) => (
        <Route
          key={path}
          path={path}
          element={<Component />} // <-- ReactNode/JSX
        />
      ))}
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

See the [Migrate from v5](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5) guide for more details on all the breaking changes from v5 to v6.